# using if exists or not exists in sql

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

Hi all I am writing a stored procedure in SQL for a list, like for example I have a list of items and I want to add another one, so I get the MAX(columName) and I add +1 which results in the last option. The only thing is I am filtering by person. Meaning I can see someone else's list as well and add things to it. Well my stored procedure is not working when someone doesn't have an item yet. How can I check if it exists first?

```
DECLARE @MAXID INT
SET @MAXID = (SELECT MAX(priority)+1
                FROM    Chores
                WHERE   userID = @user) 

UPDATE Chores
    SET userID= @user,
    priority = @MAXID
FROM
    Chores WITH (NOLOCK)
WHERE choreID= @iD
```

Results I am getting when I run this I get `Null` on the priority number for the item. I'm assuming because it did not find the `MAX()` of anything

As you can see I am adding a +1 to the list of items by given individual but I have a null value if the user doesn't have something already on their list.
I believe I can do an If Exists() but how would that work if i am declaring and setting the value from the get go. Also the other parameters are being passed in which is why I am not declaring them.

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.  Sample data and desired results would help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want:

```
UPDATE Chores
    SET userID= @user,
    priority = COALESCE(max_priority, 1)
FROM (SELECT c.*, MAX(CASE WHEN userId = @user THEN priority END) OVER () as max_priority
      FROM Chores c
     ) c
WHERE choreID = @iD ;
```

Comment: I'm not too familiar with COALESCE it returns the second parameter when the first one is null right or something like that?

Comment: It works from left to right returning the first non null of all arguments passed

Comment: Ah I see, looks good to me but what would be the difference from doing the above and doing an if exists set maxID = Max(...) else  set maxID = 1? Not sure if that makes sense I can alter the syntax on here.

Comment: @ppc . . . Why run multiple queries with arcane parameters when you can just run one query?

Comment: can't argue with that. I actually didn't understand too much what you had written, but I looked up some of the key words and I got it. Works like a charm. Thanks